# What does the total field indicate during an rsync?

Tags: backup, nas, rsync

I'm performing a backup of a Synology NAS to USB drives by doing an rsync in an SSH shell with the following command

```
rsync -rltv --delete --ignore-existing -O -P /volume5/Data/ /volumeUSB1/usbshare/
```

And in the output I see a line for every file as follows
Directory/Subdirectory/File.dat

```
1.50G    70%    56.64MB/s    0:00:05    (total: 6%)
```

When the file is completely copied, the following is added to the line above

```
1.50G    70%    56.64MB/s    0:00:05    (total: 6%) (xfer=#279, to-check=1028/61716)
```

I always thought the total: 6% was an indication of the total progress, but after reading up on rsync, I noticed that this was actually a request by many people, and I found a lot of posts stating that a total could not be added (or was not trivial to add) to rsync. Also, the total percentage jumps up and down (sometimes it drops back down, sometimes it increases). This leads me to think the total field is not the total progress.

But if it isnt't the total progress, then what is it?
And if it actually is the total progress, why does it bounce up and down?